# Are there any viable sound IC's in older consumer PC sound cards/modems for diy/circuitbending?

Tags: synthesizer

I watched some diy synthesizer vids on youtube, mostly APC's, and I thought since most use the 556/555's, what if we used something different. As fun as buying kits are, sometimes, we are broke, but still inspired. So, I went into my closet and found 7+ modems(mostly ISA) and 6 sound cards (all SB; vibra16 ISA, awe64 value, SB16Pro2, Live value, live platinum and audigy 2 platinum). A little research suggested the vibra 16 was the most outdated and pretty much useless, so it's now wearing a red jumper.

I couldn't find any schematics for any of the boards or IC's.

Am I totally off base thinking I can salvage an IC to use as a simple tone generator like an APC type synthesizer? I included modems in my search because I recall the sounds they made when dialing up, and I thought, hmmm, if that were modulated and probably slowed down it might work as a tone generator. I admit I am new to this, so identifying the correct chip to use and well, which pins do what is a little confusing. Oh, and modems and soundcards are also a good source for jacks (the sbpro2 actually has a volume pot, ha).

ps- this all started last wednesday when my Roland D2 arrived from a stint on ebay and the left channel is out, after running it thru test mode, I don't think it's more serious, theoretically than cold spots that will go away after being reflowed, but wanted to warm up to possibly ruining the piece of gear with a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

The modem ICs are rather limited in the sound they can generate. You have FSK (Frequency Shift Keying), which switches between two frequencies depending on the input bit's value. More advanced modulation methods include PM (Phase modulation), but that doesn't add more frequencies.
The dialler will be a DTMF (Dual Tone Multiple Frequency) generator, which generates a pair of frequencies from a limited set of eight. So that's out as well.

Creative Labs used custom chips on its SoundBlaster boards. They may be very versatile, but unless you can find a datasheet they're useless.

I looked around a bit and found the [SSG01 Sound Coprocessor IC](http://www.speechchips.com/shop/item.aspx?itemid=2), which may also be interesting. (Yes, I know you're broke.) It has a simple interface: it's controlled via EIA232 and outputs a mono audio signal. Unfortunately the link to the datasheet on the page is dead.

Comment: For circuit-bending purposes, can you just supply the clock input from a variable frequency source in order to generate whatever tone you want?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the best bet for DIY sound is probably something like an ARM chip with built-in DACs.  I'm not sure they're available in convenient packages for DIY work, but someone may make homebrewing modules with the parts pre-soldered and the DAC output pins exposed on a header.  An ARM should be able to do a decent job of generating multi-voice FM or wave-table synthesis, and probably throw in some FIR or IIR filtering as well.  FYI, I'm not familiar with the particular "sound coprocessor IC" mentioned, but I strongly suspect it's something like a PIC 18Fxx.  An ARM chip would be far more capable than that, probably for comparable cost.

Comment: Dont forget the dsPIC, in particular the [dsPIC33FJ128GP804](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en532299) has 2x16-bit D/A @ 100ksps with 256x oversampling and it comes in a DIP package. [This synth](http://www.frequencyresponse.ch/?p=dspicsynth)  is based on one

Comment: Have you heard of the Chipophone? It is an AVR-based synthesizer built into an organ. http://www.linusakesson.net/chipophone/index.php

Comment: My parents had a Conn Minuet organ (circa 1967) which I'd been considering doing something like that with.  I didn't really have the space for such a project, and I wasn't keen on junking the guts, though the organ might have been destined for the scrap heap anyway if my parents hadn't found someone who wanted it.  I've never used an ARM for making music myself, though I did a PIC-based music box (8 voice @10MHz) around 1996 and a PSOC-based one (16 voice @24Mhz) around 2004.

Answer (score 0):

While likely inferior to more modern solutions in both cost and ease-of-use, it's entirely possible to interface 8 (or less conveniently) 16-bit ISA cards to embedded projects.

However:

- Parallel interfaces are less convenient for many embedded projects than serial busses such as SPI
- Drivers and on-board bios extensions would have to be re-written, since they won't work on your embedded processor or its operating system (if any).  Cards for which sufficient low-level programming information is available would be a requirement - those with open source drivers would be good examples.
- you will need 5v tolerant I/O
- You will have to supply not only 5v power, but possibly also 12v especially if the board uses that to derive its own cleaner analog supply.
- they are big and clunky and power hungry by modern standards
- If you go this route, make sure you have more than one of the board - nothing worse than doing a lot of work around irreplaceable hardware and then accidentally breaking it.